# Error sending emails "Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessage"

Tags: email, sales, smtp, mageplaza

Every time magento has to send an email to the customer either for sale, or for anything that has to do with operations that require sending an email to the customer.

I have checked the log system.log and it shows me the following error

```
[2020-05-27 00:03:26] main.ERROR: Content must be string or resource; received "Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessage" [] []
```

Before I installed **Mageplaza SMTP**, I have configured it and the test does send me an email correctly